# kayak api with php

Tags: php, api

i want to do a website wich is having search functionality. in this i have to do search flights,hotels etc.., some one suggested me to use kayak api for this. i searched every thing for this. but i didn't get any idea. anyone could suggest me how to use this api in my site.

thanks.

---

i ust tried like this. here i was stucked.

```
  <? ob_start(); session_start();  
$hostname="http://www.kayak.com";
    $token="mCHpMz2L_a_OrEkz3FSiDg";//"mCHpMz2L_a_OrEkz3FSiDg";
    $sessionid="";  $searchid="";   
$searchtype="";      $lastcount=""; 
class ksearchphpExample  {

         public function ksearchJavaExample($args){     
/*print_r($args);    echo
count($args);exit;*/        if(count($args)
< 4 || count($args) > 5) {
            echo("USAGE:\n".
                "ksearchJavaExample f ORIGIN_AIPORT DESTINATION_AIRPORT
DEPART_DATE [RETURN_DATE]\n".
                "ksearchjavaExample h \"city, RC, CC\" CHECKIN_DATE CHECKOUT_DATE\n" );
            exit();         }
                $searchtype='h'; //$args[0].charAt(0);
            $sessionid= getsession();       echo("Session ID:\t".$sessionid );
                if($searchtype == 'f' ){            $searchid= start_flight_search("n",
$args[1],$args[2],$args[3],$args[4] );
        }
                if( $searchtype == 'h'){            $searchid=
start_hotel_search($args[1],$args[2],$args[3]);
        }       echo("Search ID:\t".$searchid);
        while (pollResults()) {
            echo("waiting for more...");        }   }

 private function getsession(){

        echo("Token:\t\t".$token  );        $xml
= simplexml_load_file($hostname."/k/ident/apisession?token=".$token
);

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)  
{   echo $child->getName() . ": " .
$child . "<br />";   }
        $response=get($hostname+"/k/ident/apisession?token=".$token
);
            $root=xmlRoot($response);       $sessionid=$root.getElementsByTagName("sid");
        if( $sessionid.getLength() == 0){
            echo("BAD TOKEN: ".$response);
            exit(1);        }       return
$sessionid.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    }

 //private function fetch($urlstring){
//        $content = ""; //    //         try {
//          $url  = new URL($urlstring);  
//          InputStream is =
url.openStream(); //           
BufferedReader d = new
BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(is)); //         
String s; //             //         while
(null != (s = d.readLine())) { //       
content = content + s + "\n"; //         
} //            is.close(); //          
//        } catch ( Exception e ) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage() ); }
//        return content; //        } //    
//  public static void main(String[]
args) { //      ksearchJavaExample ks =
new ksearchJavaExample(args);        // }

  } $kps=new ksearchphpExample();
$arg= array
('h','hyderabad,india','03/11/2010','05/11/2010');
echo $kps->ksearchJavaExample($arg);  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.kayak.com/labs/api/search/

Seems like you need to get a developer key. Once you've got that, you can POST their server for data, and parse the XML they return (note that their searches take 30-60 seconds to complete, so you have to request a search, catch the Search ID, then check back for the results using the Search ID). Check out the [API spec](http://www.kayak.com/labs/api/search/spec.html).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class to handle this, it can be viewed here http://kidtwist.uphero.com

feel free to use it and modify it, I created it for a simple statistical study, so it is very basic.